# Not able to set nativeElement.style.width in ngOnChanges

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to set the width of these containers, but I need to also watch for changes on my `@Input` as the DOM changes based on the `@Input`

```
@Input('connections') public connections = [];

@ViewChildren('containers', { read: ElementRef }) chipContainers: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

The value of this `@Input` can change, so I need to use `ngOnChanges`

```
  public ngOnChanges() {
    if (this.connections) {
      const containerArr = this.containers.toArray();

      if (containerArr.length) {
        containerArr.forEach((container) => {
          const child = container.nativeElement.children;

          if (child.length) {
            const baseWidth = child[0].clientWidth + 100; // omitted calc to find baseWidth

            container.nativeElement.style.width = `${baseWidth}px`;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

It seems like after setting `container.nativeElement.style.width`, the changes aren't rendered properly, as I can see the new width value when I `console.log` it.

Tried `` this.renderer.setStyle(chipContainer.nativeElement, 'width', `${baseWidth}px`); ``
but that didn't work either for some reason

Comment: Try using a debugger to look step by step if the variables have the values you are seeking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to use the `AfterViewInit` lifecycle hook instead of `ngOnChanges` to ensure that the DOM is fully rendered before attempting to modify the width of the containers.

Comment: Yes, put those calculations in `AfterViewChecked` and it worked.